# Flutter: Using Hero Animation with ListView Builder

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am building *List* (**ListView.builder**) and *Detail* Screen. **Hero** is used to animate some part when widget is selected (using **pushedReplacement**).

I noticed that when I move from *Detail* Screen to *List* screen, if the selected widget is the *end/tail/last* widget of the **ListView**, then the animation won't run.

Because **ListView.builder** is only rendering the *first/head* viewable element, I think **Hero** does not know the location of the widget.

So, how do I solve this problem? It's not that critical, but it's bugging me for days.

Comment: Hi, did you solve it? i could use a solution, i have a similar issue.

Answer (score 17):

Hero widget identifies the elements to animate by its tag. The tag property must be unique in order to make this work. So what you can do is:

1. Make the tag of each Hero unique. like,

   ```
   ListView.builder
   (
      itemCount: litems.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return Hero(
                   tag: "some_name"+index.toString(),
                   child: SomeChild();
                 );
      }
   )
   ```
2. Pass the index to detailed screen on click. like,

   ```
   Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => DetailedScreen(index)
                  )
   );
   ```
3. on the detailed screen create the tag using the index received. like,

   `tag: "some_name"+index.toString()`

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Yes. I already did it like that. But when the listview.builder is long (so the screen hide the rest of the list), the hero animation will only work for the front widgets

Comment: what do you mean by front widgets? the widgets which are visible?

Answer (score 2):

what u need is to provide unique tag to each list-builder element

```
Hero(
       tag: snapshot.data.documents[index]['category'],
       child: // your child ,
    ),
```